# Next.js Build error occurred ReferenceError: Component is not defined

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have an error when `yarn build`. But not occurred when `yarn dev`

Typography is my custom component. I use absolute imports using baseUrl option in tsconfig.json

next: v9.5.2
typescript: v3.9.7

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cEBX.png)

I need help

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of your code? It seems like you have either forgotten to import Typography or not imported it correctly.

Comment: You must forgot to import `Typography` in certain files. When you run `yarn build`, it will scan all your project and detect the errors. On the others hand, `yarn dev` just scan some files. So, it is probably fail when you run `yarn build` and success when run `yarn dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all comments! I resolve this problem that was code problem. As @bcjohn said, yarn dev not scan all files. So I realize code problem.

Problem code export

```
export default {
  h1
}
```

import

```
<Typography.h1>
```

Resolve code export

```
export default Typography;
```

import

```
<Typography />
```